# Codeigniter calendar not displaying correct data and set limit not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter [Calendar](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/calendar.html) library.

I have two tables that I get calendar data from my database.

1. events table
2. extra_events table

The problem I have 2 foreach loops with the second foreach loop `$query2->result_array()` it does not let me get the first events on each day from database table `extra_events` I am also trying to be able to set the limit from the extra events table but not working.

From the `extra_events` table

Example

```
Test 2 | Example 2
       | Example 3
```

It should produce

```
Test 1 | Example 1 <!-- Missing
Test 2 | Example 2
       | Example 3
```

> **Question** how can I make sure I get all the results correct for $query2->result_array().

Image

[image]

Get function

```
public function get_events($year, $month) {
        $calendar = array();

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('events');
        $this->db->where('year', $year);
        $this->db->where('month', $month);
        $query1 = $this->db->get();

        foreach ($query1->result_array() as $event) {

            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('extra_events');
            $this->db->where('events_id', $event['events_id']);
            $this->db->where('year', $year);
            $this->db->where('month', $month);
            //$this->db->limit(2);
            $query2 = $this->db->get();

            foreach ($query2->result_array() as $result) {

                if (array_key_exists($event['day'], $calendar)) {

                    $calendar[$event['day']] =  $calendar[$event['day']]  . '<br/>' . $result['event'];

                } else {

                    $calendar[$event['day']] = '<br/><b>From Events Table</b> <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i><br/>' . $event['event'] . '<hr><b>From Extra Events Table</b> <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></i>' ;

                }

            }
        }

        return $calendar;

    }
```

Database

[image]

[image]

Comment: just limit your foreach function in get_events() function.
You can limit foreach by using iteration variable as $i = 0; and run foreach while $i < 1;

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: @AliShan could you please show it with my code.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 hey can you clear bit more with an what you expected. as well as add `print_r($query->result_array())` result too

Comment: @Abdulla I have updated the question

Comment: @wolfgang1983 can you post this arrays output too. `$query1->result_array()` and  `$query2->result_array()`

Comment: @Abdulla after a few days of nutting it out I have now solved it. I have posted the code answer

Comment: @AliShan I have got it working with limit now and correct data showing. As shown in my answer.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 ok and Thank your for updating me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solved Now

I have had to create two tables and then on the model function added this line

`$calendar[$event['day']] = '<br/>' . $event['event'];`

Below first foreach for the main event and then any other extra events use the second foreach with array key exists.

> This now also lets me control how many rows are now displayed in extra
>   events foreach loop.

```
public function get_calendar_events($year, $month) {
        $calendar = array();

        $events = $this->get_events($year, $month);

        foreach($events as $event) {

            // Added line for main calendar event
            $calendar[$event['day']] = '<br/>' . $event['event'];

            // Passes main event id to extra_events get function
            $extra_events = $this->get_extra_events($event['events_id']);

            // checks if array key exists for extra event in side foreach loop
            foreach($extra_events as $extra_event) {
                if (array_key_exists($extra_event['day'], $calendar)) {
                    $calendar[$extra_event['day']] = $calendar[$extra_event['day']] . '<br/>' .  $extra_event['event'];
                } else {
                    $calendar[$extra_event['day']] =  $extra_event['event'];
                }
            }
        }


        return $calendar;
    }
```

**Calendar Model**

```
<?php

class Model_calendar extends CI_Model {

    public function add_event() {
        $data = array(
            'year' => $this->input->post('year'),
            'month' => ($this->input->post('month') > 10) ? $this->input->post('month') : '0' . $this->input->post('month'),
            'day' => $this->input->post('day'),
            'date' => $this->input->post('year') .'-'. $this->input->post('month') .'-'. $this->input->post('day'),
            'event' => $this->input->post('event'),
            'date_added' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
       );

       $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'events', $data);
    }

    public function add_extra_event() {
        $data = array(
            'events_id' => (int)$this->get_event_id(),
            'year' => $this->input->post('year'),
            'month' => ($this->input->post('month') > 10) ? $this->input->post('month') : '0' . $this->input->post('month'),
            'day' => $this->input->post('day'),
            'date' => $this->input->post('year') .'-'. $this->input->post('month') .'-'. $this->input->post('day'),
            'event' => $this->input->post('event'),
            'date_added' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
        );

        $this->db->insert($this->db->dbprefix . 'extra_events', $data);
    }

    public function get_event_id() {
        $this->db->where('year', $this->input->post('year'));
        $this->db->where('month', ($this->input->post('month') > 10) ? $this->input->post('month') : '0' . $this->input->post('month'));
        $this->db->where('day', $this->input->post('day'));

        $query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'events');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            return $row->events_id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

     public function check_event() {
        $this->db->where('year', $this->input->post('year'));
        $this->db->where('month', ($this->input->post('month') > 10) ? $this->input->post('month') : '0' . $this->input->post('month'));
        $this->db->where('day', $this->input->post('day'));
        $query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'events');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function delete_events() {
        $this->db->where("date <", date('Y-m-d'));
        $this->db->delete($this->db->dbprefix . 'events');
    }

    public function delete_extra_events() {
        $this->db->where("date <", date('Y-m-d'));
        $this->db->delete($this->db->dbprefix . 'extra_events');
    }

    public function get_calendar_events($year, $month) {
        $calendar = array();

        $events = $this->get_events($year, $month);

        foreach($events as $event) {

            $calendar[$event['day']] = '<br/>' . $event['event'];

            $extra_events = $this->get_extra_events($event['events_id']);

            foreach($extra_events as $extra_event) {
                if (array_key_exists($extra_event['day'], $calendar)) {
                    $calendar[$extra_event['day']] = $calendar[$extra_event['day']] . '<br/>' .  $extra_event['event'];
                } else {
                    $calendar[$extra_event['day']] =  $extra_event['event'];
                }
            }
        }


        return $calendar;
    }

    public function get_events($year, $month) {
        $this->db->where('year', $year);
        $this->db->where('month', $month);
        $events = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'events');
        return $events->result_array();
    }

    public function get_extra_events($events_id) {
        $this->db->limit(5);
        $this->db->where('events_id', $events_id);
        $extra_events = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'extra_events');
        return $extra_events->result_array();
    }
}
```

**Calendar Controller**

```
<?php

class Calendar extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('dashboard/model_calendar');
        $this->load->library('calendar');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

    }

    public function index() {    
        if ($this->uri->segment(3) == FALSE) {
            $year = date('Y');
        } else {
            $year = $this->uri->segment(3);
        }

        if ($this->uri->segment(4) == FALSE) {
            $month = date('m');
        } else {
            $month = $this->uri->segment(4);
        }

        $prefs = array(
            'start_day' => 'monday',
            'show_next_prev' => true,
            'month_type'   => 'long',
            'day_type' => 'long',
            'next_prev_url' => base_url('dashboard/calendar')
        );

        $prefs['template'] = '
            {table_open}<div class="table-responsive"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered calendar">{/table_open}

            {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

            {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x "></i></a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
            {heading_title_cell}<th class="text-center" colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
            {heading_next_cell}<th class="text-right "><a href="{next_url}"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i></a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

            {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

            {week_row_start}<tr >{/week_row_start}
            {week_day_cell}<td class="text-center" style="height: 5rem;">{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
            {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

            {cal_row_start}<tr class="days">{/cal_row_start}
            {cal_cell_start}<td class="day">{/cal_cell_start}

            {cal_cell_content}
                <div class="day_number">{day}</div>
                <div class="content" style="margin-top: 0;">{content}</div>
            {/cal_cell_content}
            {cal_cell_content_today}
                <div class="day_number highlight">{day}</div>
                <div class="content" style="margin-top: 0;">{content}</div>
            {/cal_cell_content_today}

            {cal_cell_no_content}
            <div class="day_number">{day}</div>
            {/cal_cell_no_content}
            {cal_cell_no_content_today}
            <div class="day_number highlight">{day}</div>
            {/cal_cell_no_content_today}
            {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

            {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
            {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

            {table_close}</table></div>{/table_close}
        ';

        $this->calendar->initialize($prefs);

        $this->model_calendar->delete_events();

        $this->model_calendar->delete_extra_events();

        $events = $this->model_calendar->get_calendar_events($year, $month);

        $data['calendar'] = $this->calendar->generate($year, $month, $events);

        if ($this->uri->segment(3) == TRUE) {
            $data['view_more'] = site_url('report/events/'.  $year .'/'. $month);
        } else {
            $data['view_more'] = site_url('report/events');
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('event', 'Calendar Event', 'trim|required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('dashboard/calender_view', $data);

        } else {

            if ($this->model_calendar->check_event() == TRUE) {

                $this->model_calendar->add_extra_event();

            } else {

                $this->model_calendar->add_event();

            }

            $this->session->set_flashdata('added_event', '<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> You have added event to your calendar!');

            redirect('common/dashboard');

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can limit foreach to get just 2 events.

limiting foreach loop in get_events() function.

```
public function get_events($year, $month) {
        $calendar = array();

        $this->db->where('year', $year);
        $this->db->where('month', $month);
        $query = $this->db->get('events');

        $results = $query->result_array();

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($results as $event) {
            if ($i < 2) {     // getting / fetching / extracting value from foreach for 2 times only
                if (array_key_exists($event['day'], $calendar)) {

                    $calendar[$event['day']] = $calendar[$event['day']] . '
                <hr/>

                <div class="text-center">
                <span class="label label-info">New</span>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="pull-left">
                <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">
                <li >'
                            . word_limiter(anchor(base_url('report/events/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/?event_id=' . $event['events_id']), $event['event']), 4) . '
                </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                <form id="form-event" action="' . base_url('dashboard/calendar') . '" class="form-inline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to remove this!\')";>
                <input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="' . $event['events_id'] . '">
                <a href="' . base_url('report/events/edit' . '/?event_id=' . $event['events_id']) . '" role="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                <button type"submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                </form>
                </div>
                </div>';
                } else {

                    $calendar[$event['day']] = '
                <div class="text-center">
                <span class="label label-info">New</span>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="pull-left">
                <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">
                <li >'
                            . word_limiter(anchor(base_url('report/events/' . $year . '/' . $month . '/?event_id=' . $event['events_id']), $event['event']), 4) . '
                </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                <form id="form-event" action="' . base_url('dashboard/calendar') . '" class="form-inline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to remove this!\')";>
                <input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="' . $event['events_id'] . '">
                <a href="' . base_url('report/events/edit' . '/?event_id=' . $event['events_id']) . '" role="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                <button type"submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                </form>
                </div>
                </div>
                ';
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }

        return $calendar;
    }
```

Comment: Does not work, for some reason will now only now show 2 results from whole calendar. On the calendar on the 26 day in image there is 3 it should show 2

Comment: you can contact me on Skype vuprojects14

Comment: sorry cannot at this time.